# Open a .csv after using Dataframe.to_csv Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there a way to open a .csv file right after using Dataframe.to_csv?

Currently, I am using os.startfile to open the .csv file in a folder (search for .csv file and open it) - but I want to open the specific .csv I just created using df.to_csv.

Here is my current code using os.startfile:

```
dirName3 = r"\\xx\xx\SourceFolder"
fn2 = [f2 for f2 in os.listdir(dirName3)\
    if f2.endswith('.csv') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirName3, f2))][0]
path3 = os.path.join(dirName3, fn2)
open1 = os.startfile(path3)
```

The above code will open the .csv file I've created but only if it is top of the folder. So if there are others in the folder it may not be at the top and may open a different file.

**I also can't specify an absolute path because the .csv name (using df.to_csv) will change day to day based on user input. I also won't be able to search by date because there may be multiple files from the same day in the folder.**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: would need more information otherwise looks like we need to guess! DataFrame.to_csv()? the file will be available for the process(es) once os has written the file to disk and removed the writing handle from it. so technically yes. <br> if you want to open a csv file, there must be a way to identify the file..some ways can be - find the file that is most recent i.e. based on modified date/time stamp, the second could be read the file and find a clue in it.

Comment: If you used `.to_csv` yourself to create it, then don't you know the filename?  Just pass that filename to `startfile`

Comment: @BrenBarn so you think I could do (instead of endswith('.csv')) something like: endswith(str(datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%y_')) + Qname1 + '.csv')? That is basically how I name the files with Qname1 being the user input. I'll give this a go to see if it works.

Comment: You should have to use `endswith` at all.  Just, when you do `to_csv`, store the filename you're saving to in a variable and then open that exact file.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after discussion with others in comments above.

Came up with this to solve the problem:

```
import os

dirName3 = r"\\xx\xx\Source Folder"
fn2 = [f2 for f2 in os.listdir(dirName3)\
    if f2.endswith(str(datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%y_')) + Qname1 + '.csv') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirName3, f2))][0]
path3 = os.path.join(dirName3, fn2)
open1 = os.startfile(path3)
```

Using f.endswith - instead of '.csv' as in my original above, I used the same information I used to write the csv (using to_csv function which isn't included here). This really only works because I have included a date stamp in the file names - because the Qname1 (user input) can be similar for different days I need the date to differentiate between files.

Cheers stackoverflow.